# Receiving a 404 response using swagger with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to hook up Swagger to a VB.Net REST API project. No matter what I try the app continues to return a 404 response when hitting the swagger/ui/index URL. Initially, on start-up I enter the following URL: http://localhost/ApiNameHere/Swagger.
IIS attempts to access (redirects to) http://localhost/swagger/ui/index. This returns a 404 response.

- Swashbuckle was used to install Swagger
- Locally, the app runs in IIS.

I have seen recommendations to delete the .vs folder. I have tried that, to no avail.

Here is the SwaggerConfig.vb file:

```
Public Class SwaggerConfig
  Public Shared Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)

    Dim thisAssembly = GetType(SwaggerConfig).Assembly
    config.EnableSwagger(
      Sub(c)
        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "ApiNameHere")
      End Sub
      ).EnableSwaggerUi()

  End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the relevant Startup.vb code :

```
Dim config = New HttpConfiguration()
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", New With {RouteParameter.Optional})
SwaggerConfig.Register(config)
app.UseWebApi(config)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am having this problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JonathanPeel - No. We never did. Ended up putting our Swagger project aside for now.

Comment: I have been putting it off for years. Every few months I spend a day on it and get nowhere.